# Can a cube of discontinuous function be continuous?

Tags: continuity

Can a cube (meaning $g(x) = f(x)^3 = f(x) \cdot f(x) \cdot f(x)$) of discontinuous function $f: D \to \mathbb{R}$ ($D$ is subset of $\mathbb{R}$) be continuous? I think it can't, since $x^3$ is injective, but I am not able to prove it or find a counterexample.

Comment: The point is not that $x \longmapsto x^3$ is injective, as much as $x \longmapsto x^{1/3}$ is continuous.

Comment: What is your domain? It matters really quite a lot.

Comment: I think the injectivity is very much to the point.  $f(x) =\sqrt x$ is also continuous on $[0,∞)$ but there are any number of discontinuous functions $g$ on that interval with $g(x)\cdot g(x)$ continuous.

Comment: No. But the cube of a non-differentiable function can be differentiable : $|x|^3$

Comment: @user3482749: Why does the domain matter?

Comment: I misspoke: it's the range that matters. If it's $\mathbb{C}$ and your domain is, say, connected, it's false (send some subset of your domain to $1$, and the rest to one of the other cube roots of unity).

Comment: I think you question could use a bit more context. Do you want a topological answer, a $\delta-\epsilon$ answer, a more general calculus answer, or what?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a function $f(x)$ is continuous, then its cube root $g(x) = f(x)^{1/3}$ is also continuous.

So the contrapositive is also true, which is:

If a function $g(x)$ is not continuous, then its cube $f(x) = g(x)^3$ is not continuous either.

(Strictly speaking, the contrapositive is actually "if the cube root $f(x)^{1/3}$ of a function $f(x)$ is not continuous, then the function $f(x)$ is not continuous either". But this is equivalent.)

Answer (score 47):

Since $\phi :  \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}, \phi(x) = x^3$, is a homeomorphism, you see that $f$ is continuous iff $\phi \circ f$ is continuous.

Comment: To lower the level of this answer, note that $\phi^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[3] x$ is also a continuous map ("homeomorphism" means a continuous, invertible map whose inverse is also continuous). So if $\phi\circ f$ is continuous, so is $f = \phi^{-1}\circ \phi \circ f$.